# Do i need to run the Django server every time I want to access the website?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, django

Specs:
AWS EC2 Micro instance
Latest Django, Python3, nginx

I've just created a Django project in a virtualenv. Everything's mapped out - nginx is catching the URLs and directing them to the correct ports.

However, I seem to be lacking something here: It doesn't make sense to manually run the Django server every time I want to access the site, right?

If I'm asking the wrong question, please let me know.

Comment: You configure your wsgi server to run as a service.

Comment: Aha! And now that's a LMGTFY situation, right?

Comment: Either that or just RTFM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to manually run the Django application server (wsgi server), but you need it to be running. So you can configure it to run as a service/daemon.

Here is a great picture on the deployment architecture of Django web application [The Full Stack Python Guide to Deployments](http://www.deploypython.com/source/theme/static/img/map.png)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Django needs to be running, but you don't/shouldn't run it manually.

You need to create a service to keep Django running, or use a application such as supervisord to do it for you
http://supervisord.org/